# How I can sort a text file for specific string?

Tags: string, bash, sorting, grep, lines

I have a text file with the following lines:

```
 Ca4  0.500001 0.000000 0.000000
 C4   0.750001 0.500000 0.000000
 O10  0.750001 0.243180 0.000000
 O8   0.652432 0.628410 -0.779621
 O12  0.847569 0.628410 0.779621
 Ca3  0.120090 0.500000 -3.035668
 C3   0.370090 0.000000 -3.035668
 O9   0.370090 -0.256820 -3.035668
 O7   0.272522 0.128410 -3.815289
 O11  0.467659 0.128410 -2.256048
 Ca1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
 C2   0.250000 0.500000 0.000000
 O4   0.250000 0.756820 0.000000
 O6   0.152432 0.371590 -0.779621
 O2   0.347569 0.371590 0.779621
 Ca2  0.620091 0.500000 -3.035668
 C1   0.870091 0.000000 -3.035668
 O3   0.870091 0.256820 -3.035668
 O5   0.772522 -0.128410 -3.815289
 O1   0.967660 -0.128410 -2.256048
```

What I want to do is simply order the lines so that "Ca" (string) lines go first and the rest of the lines keep as is.

I tried using

```
 grep "Ca" file | sort
```

but it prints only in the screen the lines containing "Ca"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have to do two filters. You can sorta avoid having to open the file twice explicitly by using `tee`:

```
< file tee >(grep ^Ca > ca) | grep -v ^Ca > noca
cat ca noca > newfile
```

If you want to internally sort the Ca part:

```
< file tee >(grep ^Ca | sort > ca) | grep -v ^Ca > noca
cat ca noca > newfile
```

If it's really important to you not to open the file twice, you can use awk:

```
awk '/^Ca/{ print }
     !/^Ca/{ na[NR]=$0; }
     END{ for(ln in na) print na[ln]; }' file
```

but this approach can use a lot of memory as it keeps the non-Ca parts until the end of processing.

Comment: That´s right!! Many thank's kojiro. I don't need sort the Ca lines at the moment but is good to know.

Comment: Anyone have a thing using just one input file??

Comment: @git ok, updated to only open the file once, using awk.

Comment: `awk '{ print NR + ($1 ~ /Ca/ ? 9000000 : 1000000) "\t" $0 }' file | sort | cut -f2- >new` but it's probably less efficient.

Comment: Ok I understood, probably is better use kojiro option. Many thanks

Comment: I was thinking something like ed command to move lines but using a string but maybe it can not be done this way...

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "Ca" file | sort;  grep -v  "Ca" file | sort
```

Will do what you need, first it will only output the sorted lines containing the "Ca" then it will print the remaining not containing the "Ca" note the "-v" parameter in grep meaning negative matching.

Also if you need the output to be in one stream you can connect the outputs using { && } syntax the command would look like this:

```
{ grep "Ca" file | sort &&  grep -v  "Ca" file | sort; }
```

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. The usual statement delimiter is newline or semicolon. Using `&&` implies that the second command is conditional on the success of the first.

Comment: It doesnt work sorry, although the file does not print, I don't want to order all lines

Comment: Then take out the `| sort`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution

```
 nl -n rz ca | awk -vOFS="\t" '/Ca/{$1="#"$2} {$1=$1}1' | sort -k1,1 | cut -f2-
```

to simplify the file is now tab separated.

Explanation: number the lines to preserve order of other rows, change the line number to key for the rows to be sorted; sort and discard the key.